# writhing in .bash_profile on Mac

Tags: mac, installation, mysql, .bash-profile

I wanna install sql. In installation process I did :

`open -t .bash_profile`. But when I wanna write something the error say:

`You don’t own the file “.bash_profile” and don’t have permission to write to it.`

`You can duplicate this document and edit the duplicate. Only the duplicate will include your changes.`

when I duplicate a copy is created but new command dose not work.

Note I tried  `sudo open -t .bash_profile` but same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692100/cannot-edit-bash-profile-on-mac-osx).

Just write

```bsh
sudo chown your_user_name ~/.bash_profile
```

and try again.